# Node.JS ER_PARSE_ERROR using mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, json, parsing

I searched hours to resolve my issue, but without results.

I'm using node.JS 12 with mysql and i'm getting a er_parse_error when doing an insert operation. Here's the code :

```
function addServer(info, callback) {
console.log(info.NOM);
connection.query("INSERT INTO serveurs (ID, NOM, EMPLACEMENT, UTILITE, MARQUE, MODELE, NUMEROSERIE, PROCESSEUR, MEMOIRE, OS, CATEGORIE, VALEUR) VALUES DEFAULT, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?", [info.NOM, info.EMPLACEMENT, info.UTILITE, info.MARQUE, info.MODELE, info.NUMEROSERIE, info.PROCESSEUR, info.MEMOIRE, info.OS, info.CATEGORIE, info.VALEUR], function (err, result) {
    callback(err, result);
});
}
```

Also i'm using JSON data to test, here's my JSON :

```
{
"NOM": "test",
"EMPLACEMENT": "1",
"UTILITE": "S",
"MARQUE": "HP",
"MODELE": "EWE",
"NUMEROSERIE": "DFER",
"PROCESSEUR": "weWE",
"MEMOIRE": "wesdf",
"OS": "ESFDdddddddddddddddddddddddddddd",
"CATEGORIE": "Cdeqawed",
"VALEUR": 988.65
}
```

Can you please me? The query looks valid but I really don't know what's happening.

Thanks

Comment: You need parentheses around the values in the `VALUES` clause i.e. `VALUES (DEFAULT, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your SQL use parentheses in your VALUES clause, like `VALUES (item1, item2)` rather than `VALUES item1, item2`